# My RDS has link to image stored in s3 how to convert that link to image in lambda python function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

Am a beginner to backend development and python. I have inserted a link of the image stored in S3 bucket in RDS, now am running a query on that table in lambda python function and it is returning a string as expected, how can I make that lambda function return an image using that link. Below is my lambda function

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
import pymysql
import json

rds_host="host"    
name="name"
password="passwdord"
db_name="DB"
port = 3306

def save_events(event):
      """
       This function fetches content from mysql RDS instance
      """

    result = []
    conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=30)

    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM bodyPart")

        for row in cur:
            result.append(list(row))
    print ("Data from RDS...")
    print (result)

    cur.close()

    print(json.dumps({'bodyParts':result}))

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    save_events(event)

    return result
```

Below is the output that function:

```
Response:

[

  [

    1,

    "Chest",

    "s3://imagename"

  ],

  [

    2,

    "Shoulder",

    null

  ],

  [

    3,

    "Arms",

    null

  ]

]
```

Comment: just a note that the cur.close() is redundant - when you create the "with" block the exit from there will close the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your response from RDS contains the bucket name and file name, I would just use boto3 to get the file. You will need to add the relevant permissions to your lambda to access your bucket.

Example:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

my_bucket = <your bucket name goes here>
my_file = <your file path goes here>

image = s3.get_object(Bucket='my-bucket', Key='my_file')
```

Getting the bucket name and file name will just require a little bit of string manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for the above solution got to know a new method for adding images. In my case, I need to display n number of images for n number of rows in a table.